# For what values of h is the matrix linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For what values of h will $\{(1,2,3),(2,-1,4),(3,h,4)\}$ be linearly independent?

This is how I set up my matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & h \\ 3 & 4 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$

After row reducing it, this is the matrix I ended up with:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -5 & h-6 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know what to do from here.

Should I have switched $R_2$ with $R_3$ in the original matrix $A$ in order to get the $h$ in position for the last pivot and then rref to answer the question?

Comment: Use the definition for linearly independence.

Comment: What you got is a tringular matrix, with nonzero entries on the diagonal. All such matrices are invertible.

Comment: Your row-reduced matrix seems to be wrong, double-check the calculations.

Comment: Your row reduction is incorrect - the last row must be $(1,0,-2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get the matrix to row reduced form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 5/2 \\
0 & 0 & h+13/2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and presumably you know that if the three vector are linearly independent the matrix in RREF must satisfy certain condition.

Comment: Thanks I fixed my mistake and got this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have three vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, you can look for values of $h$ such that: $$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & h \\ 3 & 4 & 4\end{vmatrix} \neq 0.$$Meaning, put $=$ instead of $\neq$ above, solve for $h$ - then the values you're looking for are everything except what you've found above.

Comment: Maybe the OP has not been introduced to determinants yet.

Answer (score 0):

First assume that the vectors are linearly dependent. Vectors are linearly dependent if and only if you can write a vector as a linear combination of the other vectors, i.e.
$$a\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\h\\4\end{pmatrix}.$$
From the first and third row we know
$$\begin{cases}a+2b = 3\\3a+4b=4\end{cases} \Rightarrow a=-2 \text{ and } b=2.5.$$
Since we know $a$ and $b$, we conclude that $h=-2(2)+2.5(-1) = -6.5$.

It follows that the vectors are linearly independent for $h \neq -6.5$.